# PHPStan conditional never-return

Tags: php, phpstan

I have an assert method that can fail or log an error when a `$silent` parameter is set. So my function looks like this.

```php
/**
* @param mixed $actual
* @param string $elementName
* @param bool $silent
* @return ($actual is null ? ($silent is true ? false : never-return) : true)
* @phpstan-assert-if-true !null $actual
*/
public static function assertNotNullWithLogging(mixed $actual, string $elementName, bool $silent = false): bool
```

I want to use this function like this.

```php
public function useTheMethod(): string
{
    $element = $this->getElement();
    $dateString = RegexUtil::getDateString($element->getText());
    Assert::assertNotNullWithLogging($dateString, 'Date');

    return $dateString;
}
```

Is never-return not supported in conditional return typ?

The method works like expected, but the static analysis is not working like expected. I did not finde any related issues or something in the PHPStan documentation.

Please link anything relating. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Please reproduce this on phpstan.org/try. Also you might have more luck and faster answer if you ask in PHPStan’s GitHub Issues or Discussions 